# Is there a 'not in' equivalent in GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is this possible to convert in createCriteria()?

```
SELECT * FROM node WHERE (node.type = 'act' AND nid NOT IN (SELECT nid FROM snbr_act_community)) LIMIT 10
```

I know there's a 'in' operator and here's what I have so far:

```
def c = VolunteerOpportunity.createCriteria()
def matchingActs = c.list {
    node {
        eq('type', 'act')
    }
    maxResults(10)
}
```

Just want to see if this is possible. Otherwise, I guess this is possible in HQL right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

thanks Sammyrulez for the code. got an idea from that. tested it but it didn't work. i fixed it and here's the final working code:

```
def ids = [14400 as long, 14401 as long]

def c = VolunteerOpportunity.createCriteria()
def matchingActs = c.list {
    node {
        eq('type', 'act')
        not { 'in'(ids) }
    }
    maxResults(10)
}
```

now i know how to use 'not' operator. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

not tried it myself but looking at the Grails doc and hibernate api you create nodes on this builder map with the static methods found in the Restrictions class of the Hibernate Criteria API [1](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html). So something like

```
 def c = VolunteerOpportunity.createCriteria()
def matchingActs = c.list {
    node {
        not(in('propertyName', ['val1','val2']))
    }
    maxResults(10)
}
```

Since you chain the in method (that returns a Criterion) with the not method (that takes a Criterion as argument and returns a negated version)

Comment: thanks for the sample code. got an idea on how to use 'not' operator.

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution :

```
def resultat=EnteteImputationBudgetaire.createCriteria().get{
            between("dateDebutPeriode", dateDebut, dateFin)

            and{ eq 'natureImputationBudgetaire','FONCTIONNEMENT'  }
            maxResults(1)
        }

        def resultat2=ParametragePlanBudgetaire.createCriteria().list() {
            like('composantBudgetaire','6%')
            if(resultat?.details) {
                not {
                    'in'('composantBudgetaire',resultat?.details?.imputationBudgetaire)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Grails documentation about creating criteria [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), you can use something like this:

```
not {'in'("age",[18..65])}
```

In this example, you have a property named `"age"` and you want to get rows that are NOT between 18 and 65. Of course, the `[18..65]` part can be substituted with any list of values or range you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just remembering: in this case you don't have to use parenthesis and you can use `inList`, for example:

```
not { inList 'age',[18..65] }
```