# Check constraint Grails database migration script

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails for my project. I am trying to add a new column into a table with CHECK constraint. Something like below:

```
ALTER TABLE suppliers
ADD CONSTRAINT check_supplier_name
  CHECK (supplier_name IN ('IBM', 'Microsoft', 'NVIDIA'));
```

I have to use DBM to make this change in database. I know how to add a new column, but not sure how to add a check constraint. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423020/is-there-a-not-in-equivalent-in-gorm) shows how to query it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any direct support for check constraints in the DSL however you can always use the sql command.

```
sql("ALTER TABLE suppliers ADD CONSTRAINT check_supplier_name CHECK (supplier_name IN ('IBM', 'Microsoft', 'NVIDIA'));")
```